# How to implement a MultiSelected Photo page in WP8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I know that now in Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1, it's easy to choose multi-photos using FileOpenPicker.

But in Windows Phone 8.0, only native code have access to the API, so if we have to choose multi-photos to do something(that is ,like uploading), we have to implemenet it by **toolkit:LongListMultiSelector** .

By doing this, I have a performance problem.

Here is the XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrowllViewAlbum" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="458" >
                <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector 
                    x:Name="AlbumList"
                    IsGroupingEnabled="False"
                    GridCellSize="100,100"
                    LayoutMode="Grid"
                    HideEmptyGroups="True"
                    IsSelectionEnabled="False"
                    EnforceIsSelectionEnabled="False"
                    CacheMode="BitmapCache"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                    Width="459"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AllPhotoTemplete}" Background="Black"
                />
            </ScrollViewer>
```

and in ViewModel:

```
  public void LoadAllPhotos()
    {
        Allphotos = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();
        MediaLibrary medialib = new MediaLibrary();
        PictureCollection pics =  medialib.Pictures;

        if (pics.Count!=0)
        {
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
           foreach(var pic in pics)
           {         
                   Stream stream = pic.GetImage();
                   image.SetSource(stream);
                   Allphotos.Add(image);
           }
       }
    }
```

However, during the debug, it throw out an exception of no insufficient memory.

Can you give me some idea to  optimize the function?

Thanks :-)

Comment: you asked for some ideas to optimize your function. Were you able to improve the memory consumption?

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way then implement the picker yourself.

since you are only loading the images for a preview, only load the thumbnail like:

```
var image = new BitmapImage();
image.SetSource(pic.GetThumbnail());
```